# Can't access another nested static class' method

Tags: java

I am trying to use two inner static class inside an Outer class.  Also, this is a multhithreaded code...I am trying to have multiple threads read/write to a stack.

The class runStack is supposed to have one push object of the class pushPop

When I compile, I keep getting the following message from the compiler and can't figure it out how to fix it:

The error says:  In mystack.pushPop cannot be applied to () operator1.push();

I removed the code as it was confusing people....I'll respost this once I have it figure it out.

Comment: Your code has too many flaws. Fix it first.

Comment: This doesn't look like java code.

Comment: Please add full declarations of classes.

Comment: sorry! Here is the full code....

Answer (score 0):

*Assumption*: `InnerClass1` isn't a nested static class. Add the word `static` on class declaration.